# Centralize Images in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to centralize images (both x and y axis) in a container in bootstrap. When I was working in non-responsive designs, I would just used this method:

```
.container{display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center; width:500px; height:300px;}
.container img{display:block; margin:auto;}
```

It worked fine but I can't use this method in bootstrap because the height of the container is not constant. So how can I centralize images in bootstrap?

Comment: I don't have much info to go on here but you could consiider using background image to center in both dimensions. This might be of some help to you. https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/cssref/background-position/

Comment: Yeah and I can also write some JS to update the height. But I though maybe there is a better way to do this. With only CSS.

Comment: This might help? http://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the height of the object you want to center and/or the container are unknown, you can use this trick from [csstrick](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/). In short, we introduce a pseudo element as follows:

```
/* This parent can be any width and height */
.block {
  text-align: center;
}

/* The ghost, nudged to maintain perfect centering */
.block:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
}

/* The element to be centered, can
   also be of any width and height */ 
.centered {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 300px;
}
```